# What is this place from episode 9 of Monogatari Second Season?

Tags: monogatari-series

In episode 9 of Monogatari Second Season, Shinobu says the following (around the 17:20 mark):

> 具体的には、この街中の人間を、
>
> 日本中の人間を、
>
> 世界中の人間を
>
> 吸血鬼化したのじゃろう。

Translated,

> To be more specific, I turned the people of this town,
>
> the people of Japan,
>
> and the people of the world
>
> into vampires.

The first line is accompanied by an aerial shot of the town where the story takes place; the second line by a shot of the Tokyo Sky Tree; and the fourth line by an image of an elaborate gravestone.

The *third* line is accompanied by the following picture:

[image]

What is this a picture of?

Answer (score 18):

This looks like a shot of the [**Palais des Nations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_Nations) in Switzerland, formerly the headquarters of the League of Nations, and now the home of the United Nations' Geneva branch.

[image]